# How to create store view or store programmatically and do it right in Mage 2?

Tags: magento2, store-view, programmatically, service-contract, repositories

I want to create store or store view programmatically and I use the followng code (for store view):

```
    $storeView = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Store\Model\Store::class); // Store - is a store view; Group - is a store (this is confusing)
    $storeView->setName('EN');
    $storeView->setCode('store2_en');
    $storeView->setWebsiteId(1);
    $storeView->setGroupId(2); // GroupId is a Store ID (in adminhtml terms)
    $storeView->setSortOrder(10);
    $storeView->setIsActive(true);
    $storeView->save();
```

But I see in IDE that `save()` method is deprecated. There is a repo for Store model (store view in adminhtml terms) - `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreRepository` but this class has no `save()` or `create()` method (v Magento 2.1.0 RC2).

**What is the right way to create store/store_views in Magento 2**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, **as of Magento 2.1-RC2 the Service Contracts method for store creation have not been implemented yet**.

I'm afraid you'll have to stick with the method you used for now as Magento core files uses the same method, see `Magento/Backend/Controller/Adminhtml/System/Store/Save.php` :

```
$storeModel = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Store\Model\Store');
$postData['store']['name'] = $this->filterManager->removeTags($postData['store']['name']);
if ($postData['store']['store_id']) {
    $storeModel->load($postData['store']['store_id']);
}
$storeModel->setData($postData['store']);
if ($postData['store']['store_id'] == '') {
    $storeModel->setId(null);
    $eventName = 'store_add';
}
$groupModel = $this->_objectManager->create(
    'Magento\Store\Model\Group'
)->load(
    $storeModel->getGroupId()
);
$storeModel->setWebsiteId($groupModel->getWebsiteId());
if (!$storeModel->isActive() && $storeModel->isDefault()) {
    throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
        __('The default store cannot be disabled')
    );
}
$storeModel->save();
```

The notice you get from the IDE regarding the `save()` method comes from the fact that the top level `AbstractModel` method is marked as deprecated thus, every class extending this class get the warning.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @raphael-at-digital-pianism. I have the following code to create stores ("store views" as wrote in "adminhtml"):

```
/**
 * Update/create store (frontname: "Store View").
 *
 * @param int $storeId ID to update existing store or 'null' to create new one
 * @param string $name
 * @param string $code
 * @param int $websiteId
 * @param int $groupId (frontname: "Store")
 * @param int $sortOrder
 * @param bool $isActive
 * @return \Magento\Store\Model\Store
 */
private function saveStore(
    $storeId = null,
    $isActive = false,
    $name = null,
    $code = null,
    $websiteId = null,
    $groupId = null,
    $sortOrder = null
) {
    $event = 'store_add';
    /** @var \Magento\Store\Model\Store $store */
    $store = $this->_manObj->create(\Magento\Store\Model\Store::class);
    $store->load($storeId);
    /* 'code' is required attr. and should be set for existing store */
    $event = is_null($store->getCode()) ? 'store_add' : 'store_edit';
    $store->setIsActive($isActive);
    if (!is_null($name)) $store->setName($name);
    if (!is_null($code)) $store->setCode($code);
    if (!is_null($websiteId)) $store->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
    if (!is_null($websiteId)) $store->setGroupId($groupId);
    if (!is_null($sortOrder)) $store->setSortOrder($sortOrder);
    $store->save();
    /** @var  \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager */
    $this->manStore->reinitStores();
    /** @var  \Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface */
    $this->manEvent->dispatch($event, ['store' => $store]);
    return $store;
}
```

This code works for Magento 2.1.3. I had an exception on 'store_edit' event when I changed 'default' code for default store view.

Comment: can you provide the complete code for this?

Comment: Sorry, it was too many time ago. I suppose that unknown instance props are these types: `$this->_manObj` => `\Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface`, `$this->manStore` => `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface`, `$this->manEvent` => `\Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface`. Just inject these types into your constructor using Mage DI then add this method (`saveStore(...)`)

Comment: thanks , i will try this