# Magento 2 pragmatically set storeview

Tags: magento-2.1, multistore, store-view

I am using Magento 2.1.7 and want to programatically load a specific store view on my multi-site based on what country a user is in when they arrive on our website. However in Magento 2 I am not sure how to do this. I tried doing the below. However it does not seem to work?? Any suggestions?

I have the below code

```
//lets redirect user to a country specific store based on where they are from
$myipaddressis = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$mycountryis = geoip_country_code_by_name($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

if($mycountryis =='DE')
  {
    //$this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->setCurrentStore(1);
  }
if($mycountryis =='GB')
  {
    //$this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->setCurrentStore(2);
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create store view or store programmatically and do it right in Mage 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/119907/how-to-create-store-view-or-store-programmatically-and-do-it-right-in-mage-2)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I do not want to create a store view. I want to redirect a user to an existing store view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this code in index.php

```
$myipaddressis = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$mycountryis = geoip_country_code_by_name($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);    
$store='your_default_store_code';
if($mycountryis =='DE')
  {
   $store='your de store code';
  }
$params = $_SERVER;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = $store;
$params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'store';
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

Comment: how can we do this by a extension, By overriding which class help to achieve this